# Time functions in general relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In my general relativity notes a function $f$ is called *time function*, if $\nabla f$ is time-like past-pointing.

Say that we are in Schwarzschild spacetime and I want to check if $f=t$ is a time function in the region $\{r>2m\}$. So I calculate:
$$
\nabla f = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu f\partial_\nu = g^{tt}\partial_t = -\frac{1}{1-\frac{2m}{r}}\partial_t \quad \Rightarrow\quad \nabla^tf<0\quad \Rightarrow \quad \nabla f\text{ is past-pointing}
$$
$$
g(\nabla f,\nabla f)=\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^2}g_{tt} = -\frac{1}{1-\frac{2m}{r}} <0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \nabla f \text{ is time-like}
$$
Thus $f=t$ is a time function in the region $\{r>2m\}$.

But if I want to check if $f=\pm r$ is a time function in the region $\{r<2m\}$ I already stuck when I want to check if $f$ is past-pointing. I calculate
$$
\nabla f = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu f\partial_\nu = \pm g^{rr}\partial_r = \pm \left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)\partial_r \quad \Rightarrow\quad \nabla^tf=0 \text{ ?}
$$
So I find that $f=\pm r$ is not a time function since it is not past-pointing. But this is obviously wrong (since I know that this time function is used later....)

Who can help me?

Comment: The time orientation in that region is given by $\partial_r$.

Comment: And how do I know that? Do I have to find coordinates such that the metric is diagonal and then the coordinate entry which is negative is the time coordinate?

Comment: It doesn't matter what coordinates you use the vector field $\partial_r$ is timelike, which you can see using any coordinates. Why is $\partial_r$ used for time orientation and not the other possibility namely $-\partial_r$ is a matter of convention. In fact I don't know which one is the standard choice nor even if there is a standard choice.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I can easily see the $g(\partial_r,\partial_r)<0$ for $r<2m$. But to check if $r$ is a time function I also need o check if $\nabla r$ is past-pointing (see my definition). This is where I have problems: To check if a vector is past-pointing I just look at its $t$ component. But why do I have to look at its $r$ component? You just claimed that in your first comment...

Comment: The time orientation is given by $\partial_r$ so to check whether $\nabla r$ is past or future pointing you need to see what the sign of $g(\partial_r, \nabla r)$ is. In this case it leads to the $r$ component.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But your first sentence is again "The time orientation is given by $\partial_r$". I don't understand that. Why $\partial_r$ and not $\partial_t$ or $\partial_\theta$? I think I don't know what "time orientation" means...

Comment: The time orientation is determined by a time-like vector field. In that region $\partial_r$ is such, so it determines a time orientation. Its negative determines the opposite time orientation. And there are no other possibilities. Any other time-like vector field will give you one of those two. The fields $\partial_t$ and $\partial_\theta$ are space-like in that region.